# CSS transparent to the parent color

Tags: css

So, here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4h6mw7wq/2/).

Here, you see `header` with `background` color gradient:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #827099 0%, #dc5562 100%)
```

I also have `span` with `:before` css attribute that mimics the background color behind it.

The purpose of this is to get a "cut" feature as a part of the word "THIS". You will notice that a top left portion of "T" is missing or more like hidden behind the `:before` attribute.

**The issue** I am having is that since the background color is `linear-gradient`, when the screen width changes, so does the linear-gradient (you can see by making the browser window smaller)

This change in the gradient does not reflect on the `:before` attribute and it no longer matches the background color.

Is there a way to fix this while keeping the linear-gradient of the background?

Comment: You could try applying the same gradient to the clip-triangle & giving it a larger percentage that lines up more or less with the background gradient - but that percentage is going to be relative to the clip-triangle and you'd need to add a javascript listener to re-calculate the gradients' percentage (on the triangle) when the browser is resized, or it wouldn't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is an option for your use case, but you could set the linear gradient to ensure that the color change doesn't happen until after it clears the cutout.

You would set the first stop in the gradient to be the width of the padding (118px) plus the width of the clip border (21px) and then change the clip border colors to be the same as the starting color of the gradient. In the example below I rounded up to 140px.

https://jsfiddle.net/6dvy7dks/

```
.head {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #827099 140px, #dc5562 100%);
}

span.first:before {
    border-top-color: #827099;
    border-left-color: #827099;
}
```